# jQuery Datepicker only showing sometimes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have added a simple jQuery datepicker to a form, nothing complex at all.

For some reason, in IE9 (havent tested IE8), it only shows sometimes. If you keep refreshing the page, sometimes it will show and sometimes it will not.

The page is http://hotel.danielblackmore.co.uk (Its the availability checker in the top right hand corner.

I have stripped it back and re-added it again etc but it is still only showing sometimes.

the Datepicker displays fine on the jquery website so i'm sure its something I have done, but I cannot work this out.

Has anyone expecerienced this before?

My code is:

```
    <script src="java/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="java/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var $myBadDates = new Array                ("09/05/2011","13/09/2012","12/09/2012","26/09/2012","27/09/2012","15/05/2020");

        function checkBadDates(mydate){
        var $return=true;
        var $returnclass ="available";
        $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', mydate);
        for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
            {    
               if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
          {
                $return = false;
                $returnclass= "unavailable";
                }
            }
        return [$return,$returnclass];
        }

        $(function() {
            $( "#arriving" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                minDate: new Date(2012, 9 - 1, 9),
                beforeShowDay: checkBadDates,

            });

            $( "#departing" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                minDate: new Date(2012, 9 - 1, 9),
                beforeShowDay: checkBadDates,

            });
        });
        </script>
```

I have tried without the disabled days function as well, no luck

Regards

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the issue is that the script is running and trying to execute before the DOM is loaded.  (That would also explain why it randomly works some times but not others.)  Put the Javascript code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block.

Even better, move the script blocks to the end of the document -- that's the best approach, because it allows the rest of the document to load and be displayed while the scripts are loading.